# How to solve npm install error for ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to install modules in ionic 2 , but I get the following error:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: com.pylonproducts.wifiwizard@~0.2.11

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mehmetata/.npm/ logs/2018-07-31T07 44 40 579Z-debug.log
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/  (Ok, technically I downvoted because it's an image of an error message, but the idea is the same. Don't post images of text.)

Answer (score 0):

try `npm cache clean --force` Command